# PHP Regular Expression not working : mobile format

Tags: php

I am having a problem in my code. I cant seem to solve this. 
 here is my test subject : +447799604555 
and here is my code

```
preg_match("/^\+44d{10}$/", "+447799604555");
```

is returning 0  which is false..
Don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have missed `\` before `d`. Try with following regex:

```
/^\+44\d{10}$/
```

Comment: works like charm.... Can you direct me to a blog or tutorial . I want to know why and how do I have to put \  .... or can you explain the reason...?  THank you

Comment: You have to put `\\` in the case you want to use regex built in special expressions. Look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Worth noting that whilst this obviously matches invalid phone numbers, it will also fail for some valid phone numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try `preg_match("/^\+44\d{10}$/", "+447799604555");`